# Reinstalling Mac mini (server?)

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I just got a Mac mini that I will use to play FLAC-files in my stereo (DAC to be bought). I have no idea how old it is. Might be from 2010?

The serial (on a sticker on the back of the Mac mini) is:
XSVR-106-000-R-J8m-F82-PWQ-7RJ-WHJ-L-HJ-7

However, I have problems reinstalling it. There's a sticker on the back that says: MAC OS X 10.6 SRV UNLIMITED CLIENT

The install stops after a while saying:

*No packages were eligible for install. contact the software manufacturer for assistance*

...I'm doing a Recovery-install from some sort of Recovery-disk and using the Internet. I'm signed into App Store etc.

These are the options I have at the recovery:

[image: Apple Boot Manager]

It seems like this problem could have something to do with the date?

I tried setting the date to 2017 (some sources claimed that this would to the trick) by starting in Single user mode. But I get this:
*Common missing Bluetooth controller transport*...

And can't even type in the terminal. Any ideas on how to restore this?

Comment: The first thing you want to do is get the make and model of your Mac mini...to do that, you need the serial number.   It should be on the bottom of the mini or when you’re in the installer, go to “About this Mac”. Then put that number in this site: https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/. Post your model info into your question.

Comment: Is the Mini already installed with Snow Leopard Server? Can you clarify how you're installing by "network install recovery"? Do you mean Internet Recovery? Do you have a DVD installer? What has a sticker on it - the Mini?

Comment: @benwiggy som poor writing from me (I was tired when I posted): It's Internet Recovery, using CMD+R.

Comment: @Allan I've updated the question a bit. It seems like there's no "About this Mac" at the installer, but there's a serial sticker on the back. It says "Power Mac G5" on the site you linked. That can't be right?

Comment: @benwiggy I'm not sure what's installed on it now. I was a bit tired when writing, "network install recovery" is somewhat vague. I held down option when booting and got into the options on this image: https://i.ibb.co/Qr10Kbr/IMG-20200130-101817.jpg

Unfortunately I don't hava a DVD-installer.

Comment: Post your SN number here in the comments, but it's totally possible it could be a PowerPC Mac mini.  The screen you're showing there is the Apple Boot Manager...it doesn't tell us much.  What we need is a screen capture of the Installer once it has booted.  If you go to  → About This Mac you should find the serial number.  Were you able to get a SN# off the bottom?

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the help. I gave up on this. I might return, one of these days though. We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

From your photo, it looks like the disk has two Recovery Partitions for different updates of 10.11 (El Capitan). 
It also looks to have an installer disk partition: like you would make for a USB stick in order to boot and install a version of MacOS.

I would select the first Recovery Partition (10.11.4), and from there launch Disk Utility and merge the other two partitions. Then install OS X from there.

If you've already tried installing from the Recovery Partition, and that's not working, then you could try Internet Recovery, which is what you do when the disk doesn't have a valid Recovery Partition. Option Command R.

Then try the same process from there: re-partition the disk and install the OS. It may install a different OS, but once it's done that, you can upgrade to whatever you like.

Comment: I'm doing some sort of recovery install, which I came into by holding down option while booting. It's trying to install OS X 10.11, but it doesn't work. Apparently.

Comment: I think this one is too old for Internet Recovery? I already tried that. What difference does it make merging the partitions? I think I will give up on this one. It's probably too old. Getting an install DVD might be the only option?

Comment: Do you have any other Macs? There are instructions for how to make an install USB drive from the Apple MacOs installer app, if you can download one.

Comment: I made an El Capitan-installer from my iMac. It didn't work. I gave up on this one.